# Maximize substring match in regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I would like to extract the element symbols (if present) from a word. For this, I have prepared a regex matching pattern consisting of all the symbols of elements in periodic table.

```
H|He|Li|Be|B|C|N|O|F|Ne|Na|Mg|Al|Si|P|S|Cl|Ar|K|Ca|Sc|Ti|V|Cr|Mn|Fe|Co|Ni|Cu|Zn|Ga|Ge|As|Se|Br|Kr|Rb|Sr|Y|Zr|Nb|Mo|Tc|Ru|Rh|Pd|Ag|Cd|In|Sn|Sb|Te|I|Xe|Cs|Ba|La|Ce|Pr|Nd|Pm|Sm|Eu|Gd|Tb|Dy|Ho|Er|Tm|Yb|Lu|Hf|Ta|W|Re|Os|Ir|Pt|Au|Hg|Tl|Pb|Bi|Po|At|Rn|Fr|Ra|Ac|Th|Pa|U|Np|Pu|Am|Cm|Bk|Cf|Es|Fm|Md|No|Lr|Rf|Db|Sg|Bh|Hs|Mt
```

Now, for a given word, I would like to extract the elements from it by using the above regex pattern. The problem that I face now is that for words like

```
CuIn2Se
```

I am able to extract

```
C,In,S
```

as the elements. This is an incorrect extraction as I need

```
Cu, In, Se
```

from the regex whereas I am getting "C,In,S" and I believe the reason for this is that the matching pattern sees "C" before "Cu" and "S" before "Se" (for e.g., the current matching pattern is like)

```
C | In | S | Cu | Se
```

To solve this problem, I think, I would have to ensure that regex matches maximum number of characters in my word by searching all the words in the pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The right way to do that is by arranging all your elements in decreasing order of their length

```
>>> import re
>>> pat = re.compile('Cu|In|Se|C|S')
>>> s = 'CuIn2Se'
>>> pat.findall(s)
['Cu', 'In', 'Se']
```

This is clearly explained in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

*Small Note*

Given that your input string is very long, I have written a small script that makes it sort in decreasing order of length. It might be of help to you

```
'|'.join(sorted(s.split('|'),key = len,reverse = True))
```

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion, I can definitely do that (by sorting my regex pattern based on the number of characters). I am wondering whether is there any other way that I can use without changing the order of words in my regex pattern.

Comment: @Nakamura Added a script to help you sort the input. You can put that inside a black box!

Comment: Thanks very much, yeah, I am proceeding now to sort my words in the regex pattern and use the modified pattern during regex matching.

Comment: I can't find this in the docs. Can you say where on that page it is?

Comment: I now believe it really isn't on that page you linked to and I suggest you link to [this one](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) instead, which does say it.

Comment: @StefanPochmann Thanks. I read the HowTo and it is not mentioned there, so obviously it is mentioned in the docs. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the [regex](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) module's named list:

```
>>> import regex
>>> s='H|He|Li|Be|B|C|N|O|F|Ne|Na|Mg|Al|Si|P|S|Cl|Ar|K|Ca|Sc|Ti|V|Cr|Mn|Fe|Co|Ni|Cu|Zn|Ga|Ge|As|Se|Br|Kr|Rb|Sr|Y|Zr|Nb|Mo|Tc|Ru|Rh|Pd|Ag|Cd|In|Sn|Sb|Te|I|Xe|Cs|Ba|La|Ce|Pr|Nd|Pm|Sm|Eu|Gd|Tb|Dy|Ho|Er|Tm|Yb|Lu|Hf|Ta|W|Re|Os|Ir|Pt|Au|Hg|Tl|Pb|Bi|Po|At|Rn|Fr|Ra|Ac|Th|Pa|U|Np|Pu|Am|Cm|Bk|Cf|Es|Fm|Md|No|Lr|Rf|Db|Sg|Bh|Hs|Mt'
>>> p=regex.compile(r"\L<options>", options=s.split('|'))
>>> p.findall('CuIn2Se')
['Cu', 'In', 'Se']
```

Comment: That's neat!  I was checking to see if the `regex` module supports `\G` (which it does), but a named list is perfect for this job.

Answer (score 1):

Another simple way

```
x="CuIn2Se"
print re.findall(r"(?:C|In|S|Cu|Se)(?=[A-Z0-9]|$|\s)",x)
```

[Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aH9gG5/2#python)

Answer (score 0):

I'd take a different approach, just to be different. Rather than listing out all the compounds in one big regex, it might be faster to make them a set, grab everything that *might* be a compound, and filter it after the fact.

```
import re

molecule = "CuIn2Se"

compounds = re.findall("[A-Z][a-z]?", molecule)

all_compounds = set(("H, He, Li, Be, B, C, N, O, F, Ne, Na, Mg, "
                     "Al, Si, P, S, Cl, Ar, K, Ca, Sc, Ti, V, "
                     "Cr, Mn, Fe, Co, Ni, Cu, Zn, Ga, Ge, As, Se, "
                     "Br, Kr, Rb, Sr, Y, Zr, Nb, Mo, Tc, Ru, Rh, Pd, "
                     "Ag, Cd, In, Sn, Sb, Te, I, Xe, Cs, Ba, La, Ce, "
                     "Pr, Nd, Pm, Sm, Eu, Gd, Tb, Dy, Ho, Er, Tm, "
                     "Yb, Lu, Hf, Ta, W, Re, Os, Ir, Pt, Au, Hg, Tl, "
                     "Pb, Bi, Po, At, Rn, Fr, Ra, Ac, Th, Pa, U, Np, "
                     "Pu, Am, Cm, Bk, Cf, Es, Fm, Md, No, Lr, Rf, Db, "
                     "Sg, Bh, Hs, Mt").split(", "))

actual_compounds = filter(lambda ch: ch in all_compounds, compounds)
```

This should be faster if you have tons of strings to search, since testing set membership is much faster than a regex parse. If you just have a few, the cost of building the set might outweigh the speed in parsing the strings. The golden rule is to profile your code and remember that *premature optimization is the root of all evil*